# Performance of an algorithm based on comparison

Tags: performance, algorithm

I have an algorithm written in Java, in which I need to make sure a function call is not repeated if it has already been made. Let me explain the logic:

1. There is a set of functions available: function 1, function 2, ..., function n with their parameters,
2. A function 1 call is made with a set of values as parameters and produces a result,
3. The function 1 call, the values passed as parameters, and the result produced are stored in memory,
4. When a function 2 call is made, the function 2 call, its values passed as parameters and the result are stored in memory,
5. When a function 1 call is made again, with different values as parameter, the new call (that's it, its values and result) is stored in memory,
6. Now, when a function 1 call is made again, with the same values as parameters as in 2 above, since the exact same call has been previously made, we don't want to execute again the function call but we need to retrieve the result that was stored in 2 above.

Our current strategy is to store in a map the function calls, their values and their results. For each new function call, we look in the map first if that function has been called already. If so, we compare one by one the values passed in the function call with the ones of previous function calls stored in memory.

As the number of function calls grows, we have some performance issue. For each new call, we compare each values with the stored values in memory.
So when we've called 100,000 times function 1 with different values each time and I call function 1 again with values A, B, C that have never been used previously, I need to compare 100,000 times A, B and C with the stored values of the 100,000 previous function calls. And then there is another call, I compare again 100,001 times.

Performance gets worse to a point where it is very very slow. Would you have some hints on how to improve that algorithm please?

Comment: creating a hash table of some sort? Combined with a linked list (it might get a little messy in places for implementation - could possibly be some sort of help

Comment: The problem is not about the data structure to use in Java. It is about the algorithm strategy to follow I guess. I'm sure there is something in the logic we've put in place using comparison a lot that could be improved...

Comment: sorry, i meant sending the set of values to a hash table, and see if they have been called by that function before? if true, then there is a duplite call. If not, then it's new

Comment: A map of maps will solve the problem. Use the type of function call as a key to the first map, and the list of parameters as a key to the second map. You'd be done in constant time in most of the cases.

Comment: A quick search on the term *memoization in Java* turns up a bunch of useful approaches.  Useful and performant ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, thanks, that looks promising - I need to get more familiar with it. What do you think of the answer of Matthias below please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not just store the type of the function as the key for the map, but the whole call with all arguments. Therefore it will be necessary to write a FunctionCall class as Key. It might look like this:

```
enum Funtions{Funktion1, Funktion2, Funktion3};

class FunctionKey(){
    public Functions function;
    public int value1
    public int value2

    public int hashCode(){
        int result = 1 + function.ordinal();
        result = result * 31 + value1;
        result = result * 17 + value2;
        return result;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj){
        if (!(obj instanceof FunctionKey))
              return false;
        FunctionKey that = (FunctionKey) obj;
        return function == that.function && value1 == that.value1 && value2 == that.value2;
    }
}
```

If you build up a HashMap with such a key, and the result of the function as the value, you will be able to retreive the old values in constant time. If there is no value in the map, just store such a key along with the new value.

Function1 might now look like this:

```
Map<FunctionKey, Integer> cache = new HashMap<>();

int function1(int value1, int value2){
    FunctionKey key = new FunctionKey(Functions.Function1, value1, value2);
    Integer result = cache.get(key);
    if (result==null){
        result = oldFunction1(value1, value2);
        cache.put(key, result);
    }
    return result;
}
```

If the Functions return different datatypes it becomes a bit more clumsy (maybe one map per function will do).

This concept is called caching.

Comment: Thanks, the comparison logic is still present: function == that.function && value1 == that.value1 && value2 == that.value2. You push the comparison logic on the map, but as the map grows, the performance to compare will be worse.

Comment: No, it won't. Try it out. HashMaps have constant access time. These comparisons are only done a constant number of times per get. How many comparisons you need exactly depends on details of the map. But usually it should be on average less than three, no matter how large the map will grow.

Comment: worked very well - I could improve the performances of my algorithm: went from 20 minutes to 2 minutes. Thanks!